# DNS! Use Bluehost domain with Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

How can I use my existing Bluehost Domain with Azure? I have done creating a CNAME and A record on bluehost but when I try to visit my site the address i am seeing is the mysite.azurewebsites.net and not mysite.com has anyone tried this before ? hope anyone could help thanks in advance.

Comment: You also need to configure  custom DNS name to your Azure Web App. Please refer to this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain

Answer (score 0):

As Wayne said, you need to **configure custom DNS name to your Azure Web App**.

In the left navigation of the app page in the Azure portal, **select Custom domains**.

**Create a CNAME record**:

Select "Add hostname", fill your website name + domain name into Hostname and choose "**CNAME**", finally click "Add hostname". You will be able to browse your hostname in Explorer.

[image]

**Create the A record**:

Select "Add hostname", fill your  website name + domain name into Hostname and choose "**A record**", finally click "Add hostname". You will be able to browse your hostname in Explorer.

[image]

For more detail, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain).